# Pair (C++) with V8

Tags: v8

I try to comprehend how to wrap C++ code in V8. 
It`s clear, how to do it, when create smth like 'hello world':

```
static Handle<Value> hello(const Arguments& args)
{
    HandleScope scope;
    return scope.Close(String::New("hello_world"));
}
```

I`d like to wrap the next function:

```
void foo ()
{
 pair <string, int> f ( "Size", 30 );
 pair <string, int> s ( "Number", 12 );
 cout << "first " << f.first << ", " << f.second << endl;
 cout << "second " << s.first << ", " << s.second << endl;
}
```

But the problem is: I have no ideas how to do it.